# Trouble calling C++ code from MATLAB 2016 using a helper C file w/MEX Wrapper

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex, extern

I need to call a C++ non-member function from MATLAB 2016. MATLAB did not support C++ MEX until 2018, so this poses an issue.

I am doing this in Windows under mingw64.

To get around this, I attempted to make a C file with a MEX wrapper, with the C implementation purely just calling the C++ function using a shared header file with extern "C" based on some advice online.

However, I am very new to MATLAB, calling C++ from C and some other concepts here. So nothing compiles properly whatsoever.

Any advice on properly approaching this is greatly appreciated.

The header file myFunc.h:

```
#ifndef CPP_H
#define CPP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
void myFunc(const std::vector<myStruct>& a,
            const std::vector<myStruct>& b,
            const double c,
            std::vector<std::pair>& d,
            mxArray **e
            );
extern "C" {
#endif
void myFunc(const std::vector<myStruct>& a,
            const std::vector<myStruct>& b,
            const double c,
            std::vector<std::pair>& d,
            mxArray **e
            );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

The C file to call it, myFuncCaller.c:

```
#include "myFunc.h"
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    myFunc(prhs[0], prhs[1], prhs[2], prhs[3], prhs[4]);
}
```

The actual implementation:myFunc.cpp:

```
#include "myFunc.h"

void myFunc(const std::vector<myStruct>& a,
            const std::vector<myStruct>& b,
            const double c,
            std::vector<std::pair>& d,
            mxArray **e
            )
{
  //things done here, pushes results to d
}
```

The end result of trying to compile both of these is that:

- the C file doesn't see mex.h (unsure why, as MATLAB claims that mingw is complaint)
- the header file is likely all wrong, and claims that "type defaults to int in declaration of std". I'm assuming it's because I have some C++-related things in a C section. I'm not sure how to approach this.
- The C++ file complains the most. I could post all the errors, but I don't think it would be productive considering there's likely a fundamental flaw in my logic.

One large hurdle is the approach of passing input arguments from MATLAB -> C -> C++. I don't want things to be "lost" and ideally don't want to do conversion unless necessary, and I'm not sure where that would be.

Comment: One thing to note (but probably not the only thing missing here) The class of `prhs[0], prhs[1], ...` is `*mxArray`, but your function is expecting `std::vector`, so you'll have to make that conversion. If you use the C++ MEX API the inputs will be `matlab::data::Array` stuffed inside of `matlab::mex::ArgumentList`.

Comment: Since I'm using MATLAB 2016 there is no C++ MEX API sadly, or I would use those. Working on figuring that out atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot put `std::vector<>` in an `extern "C"` section, as it's not valid C syntax. You need to create a pure C function stub, compiled as C++, that calls the C++ function.
2. But, you don't need to do any of that because you can compile a C++ MEX-file just fine. The API is C, but you can call C functions from C++ without problem.
3. The actual problem in your `mexFunction` is that you pass pointers to `mxArray` objects where the function expects references to `std::vector<>` etc. The only way to do this right is to copy the data from the MATLAB array into a C++ vector:

```cpp
#include "myFunc.h"
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
   if (nrhs < 5) {
      mexErrMsgTxt("Not enough input arguments! 5 expected.");
   }

   // arg 1: std::vector<myStruct>
   if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0])) {
      mexErrMsgTxt("First input argument must be a double array.");
   }
   std::size_t N = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
   double* pr = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
   std::vector<myStruct> a(N);
   std::copy(pr, pr+N, a.begin());

   // arg 2: std::vector<myStruct>
   std::vector<myStruct> b; 
   // ...

   // arg 3: double
   double c = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);

   // arg 4: std::vector<std::pair> // This makes no sense in C++, std::pair<> is a template, 2 template arguments missing!!
   std::vector<std::pair> d;
   // ...

   // arg 5: mxArray **  // is this the output? Why does your C++ function take an mxArray?

   myFunc(a, b, c, d, &prhs[4]);
}
```

Comment: For context, it wasn't std::pair specifically, but something that used that template. I should've been more clear. It is a pair of unsigned integers. Also, the mxArray is not actually the output. If anything, argument 4 (the pairs) would be the output as it's a pointer to a vector which should be filled using push_back by the function. I'll look over this code and your reply some more, I think this might be the road to a solution for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Tyler: If you can change `myFunc`, you can pass the MATLAB data without copy. You'd have to have a `double*` and a `std::size_t` input arguments instead of each `std::vector`.

Comment: I can modify myFunc all I want, except what arguments it takes. Those must remain unchanged. (It's part of a larger software development project and relies on/uses specific user-defined data types that may change in the future)

Comment: I'm running into an issue with mex.h not being found. I'll make another issue about it, so it might be a couple days before I reply to this original post and let you know whether my efforts succeeded.

Comment: @Tyler: Are you compiling the MEX-file with the `mex` command in MATLAB? Compiling it with `gcc` is quite hard, you need to set a lot of things just right. If you use the `mex` command, and it doesn't find `mex.h`, maybe you need to run `mex -setup` first.

Comment: I don't follow. This is a C++ file with both myFunc and the mexFunction. (As per your suggestion) How can MATLAB 2016 compile that? My MATLAB script does do ```mex myFunc.cpp``` but I thought that was just to let MATLAB know there was a MEX function inside, not to actually compile the entire file. Does MATLAB call G++ or similar in this case? And would mex -setup be run from MATLAB?

Comment: @Tyler: Yes, `mex` is a MATLAB function, call it from within MATLAB. `mex myFuncCaller.cpp myFunc.cpp` will compile both files into a single MEX-file called `myFuncCaller` (i.e. the first file name given). You can add all sorts of GCC flags to that command line too, to set C++ version, link in libraries, etc. Do `doc mex` in MATLAB to read the documentation. Use `mex -setup` to configure which compiler MATLAB uses.

Comment: Well again, isn't the problem that I'm in MATLAB 2016? It won't have any C++ related functionality, will it? Also: I removed myFuncCaller.cpp, since it was suggested to move the mexFunction into myFunc.cpp. Also, if I do manage to compile with G++ (which seems like it might be working, though I am getting many errors) then how will my script see it? Can I just call myFunc inside my MATLAB script and it'll look inside the current directory for any .o files as well?

Comment: @Tyler: MATLAB didn't have a C++ API in 2016, but it did support C++ MEX-files. Read the documentation to `mex` and you'll see. (BTW, what they now call C-API used to be called the C/C++ API!) Don't try to compile with `g++` yourself, there are lots of things to configure just right (libraries, include directories, preprocessor defines, etc.), it is not trivial and not documented. It's not worth your time to figure this out. Just use the `mex` script. You can call if from the shell also if you really need to, in Linux it's called `mex.sh`.

Comment: @Tyler: `.o` files are not executable. `mex` creates a `.mex***` file (the name changes depending on your platform). This file will be treated as a function in MATLAB, you can call it by typing its name minus extension. It has to be either in the current directory on in a directory on the MATLAB path (see the function `addpath`).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for all the help! I won't be able to do more testing and debugging until tomorrow, but this has helped an absolute ton. Lifesaver!

Comment: Alright, so when I attempt to do ```mex myFunc.cpp``` (which has the C-style mexFunction inside) it says "no supported compiler or SDK was found".

Comment: (To be clear, right now I *just* have myFunc.cpp and the Matlab script to call it. I have no header file, no myFuncCaller, since I was under the impression those wouldn't be needed from our earlier discussion)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194258/discussion-between-tyler-shellberg-and-cris-luengo).